Can the CG paper questions be asked on `computer graphics` site?
In a paper of computer graphics:

there is category description:

CR Categories: I.3.6 [Computer Graphics]: Methodology and
Techniques—Interaction techniques;

I have questions about it:

What are the criteria for this classification based on? Where can we find this criterion?

Where to list all the papers of this specified category?

Can the questions upper be asked on computer graphics site?



The short answer to the 1. & 2. is that it depends on the publisher. For example, consider the Journal of Computer Graphics Techniques (JCGT) and the ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG).
TOG uses the 2012 ACM Computing Classification System (CCS)
which "relies on a semantic vocabulary as the single source of categories and concepts" to identify the keywords and categories for a given paper. It's not immediately clear to me what taxonomy the CCS currently was built from; earlier version drew heavily from a taxonomy report from the American federation of Information Processing Societies. You can filter papers using the categories & keywords in the ACM Digital Library. You can also explore the CCS more directly though I found the response time to be slow.
In contrast, JCGT doesn't use categories or keywords at all. You can search for papers of interest using their web search tool on their Read page.
So for your specific example above, you'll likely need to research how that specific publisher classifies papers.
I don't spend a lot of time on this Stack, but here are my thoughts regarding 3: Questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic. So  I would anticipate asking something like "where can I get all the papers on procedural cellular noise?" would get closed. If you are looking for something but don't know what it is called such as "what should I look for to find papers on procedurally generating textures that look like this", that's probably on-topic. Because questions are generally better received when they show clear research effort, I would suggest including information about where & how you searched as well as how the results differed from your expectations.
